# I want to find a specific data (python,pandas,seaborn)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, jupyter-lab

I want to find specific data about classes and gender. Like, They are 100 male and 102 female in First Class.
I tried using groupby method, i can reach number of males and females but cant find attach with their classes.
I also tried groupby("class")["sex"].count() but i didnt get what i want
Furthermore, i tried filter function to make a filter but my brain suddenly stopped working.

Can you help me please? and if you can, can you show me how to use filters in this case please.
Thank you already
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmomo.png)

Comment: I imported seaborn's titanic data btw

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the tour and take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to know how to group and count by two columns. This is done easily using

```
df.groupby('class').sex.value_counts().unstack()
```

For your case, this yields

```
sex     female  male
class
First       94   122
Second      76   108
Third      144   347
```